# How to implement two color scales in one ggplot2 graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, viridis

I am trying to plot a ggplot2 graph but using two different colour scales, one user defined and one defined by a separate column in my data.frame.

This is easier shown in an example:

```
gene   chr     start       end    aceth   acvitd disttss    density       fc     color
1   MAP6D1  chr3 183527379 183528379 1.458988 2.190145 15514.0 0.06652449 1.501140 increased
2  MIR6729  chr1  12111873  12112873 1.581880 2.373651 23159.0 0.06244715 1.500525 increased
3 ATP6V0A4  chr7 138440797 138443072 1.517358 2.276540 41006.5 0.06244715 1.500331 increased
4    PRKCQ chr10   6560041   6562565 2.054282 3.081668 61305.0 0.01572513 1.500119 increased
5   UBE2L6 chr11  57327153  57329079 0.972952 1.458081  7687.0 0.12156697 1.498615 unchanged
6  FAM109B chr22  42469873  42471646 1.150138 1.723444   505.5 0.18451594 1.498468 unchanged
```

I can plot the following graph using this code:

```
heatmap <-  ggplot(acall, aes(aceth, acvitd,labels=gene, colour = density)) + scale_color_viridis()
heatmap + theme_bw(base_size = 14) # same theme as other graphs
heatmap <- heatmap + geom_point()
```

Which gives me a nice gradient fill in my graph using the gradient column in my data.frame.

[image: Gradient filled scatter plot]

However I then would like to label the genes with fc greater or less than a cutoff in different colors but keep the unchanged genes in this gradient fill.

I can do the first part with:

```
cols <- c("red" = "red", "unchanged" = "darkgrey", "increased" = "#00B2FF", "decreased" = "#00B2FF")

heatmap <-  ggplot(acall, aes(aceth, acvitd,labels=gene, fill = color))
heatmap <- heatmap + scale_y_continuous(trans = "log") + scale_x_continuous(trans = "log")
heatmap <- heatmap + geom_point(size = 2.5, alpha = 1, na.rm = T, shape = 21, colour = "black")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = cols)
```

This gives me a nice plot with "increased" and "decreased" genes in one color and "unchanged" in darkgrey. As well as some highlighted points referring to specific genes I named in the "color" column earlier.

[image: non gradient scatter]

What I would like to do is plot the "unchanged" genes (so the points in grey in the second plot) in the "color" column with a gradient fill and the rest with my defined color scheme.

Thanks

Comment: I would probably add the points in two layers, one for the unchanged and one for the others, and then use `fill` for one layer and `color` for the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't provide an example with all the combinations of data, I made some up in a similar structure.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(
    gene   = sample.int(5000),
    aceth  = rnorm(5000), 
    acvitd = rnorm(5000)
  ) %>% 
    mutate(
      dens = dnorm(aceth) + dnorm(acvitd),
      chg  = ifelse(density < 0.4 & abs(acvitd) > 2, "changed",   "unchanged"),
      dir  = ifelse(sign(acvitd) == 1,               "increased", "decreased"),
      dir  = replace(dir, gene %in% sample.int(5000, 30), "special annotation")
    )


 ggplot() + 
   geom_point(data = filter(df, chg == "unchanged"), 
              aes(aceth, acvitd, color = dens)) + 
   geom_point(data = filter(df, chg == "changed"), 
              aes(aceth, acvitd, fill = dir), 
              shape = 22, size = 3) +
   scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey70", "white", "red")) +
   scale_color_viridis() +
   theme_bw()
```

[image]

You can alter the aesthetics to match what you want, but this is how I would achieve that sort of plot.

Comment: I am trying it out now, could you give me a clue how to specify more than one argument to

geom_point(data = filter(df, chg == "changed")

So in your example "increased" and "decreased"

or would I need to make one "changed" as you did?

Comment: @reubenmcg, I made two columns `chg` and `dir` because that was easiest, but you could use one column like yours and say something like `filter(., color %in% c("decreased", "increased", "red"))`

Comment: Got it, I am not 100% sure about all the syntax you provided as I am not experienced enough to understand, but I managed to split the columns using simple code, then it all made sense. Thanks

For others like me I split the columns with mutate function: acall <- mutate(acall, dir = case_when(acall$fc > 1.5 ~ "increased",
                                          acall$fc < 0.666666 ~ "decreased"))

Comment: Brian, sorry. I am trying to add gene labels using the geom_label_repel function, but when I try to put "label = gene" into the aes(), I keep getting errors like. Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: label or :object 'gene' not found. Any ideas?

Comment: @reubenmcg, yes, you needed to update the columns to indicate the change based on your chosen cutoff, **fc**, glad you got that working. I'm not familiar with the `ggrepel` package, but it should work the same as `geom_label(data = df, aes(label = gene))`. Make sure to include the data argument, since there's no data in the initial `ggplot()` call in my code.